# Troubles with installation of PHPUnit 4.0 through PEAR - no PHPUnit folder in include path

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, debian, pear

I'm having troubles after installing the current PHPUnit version. I'm trying to reproduce a virtual machine I set up before. To that time I installed PHPUnit trough PEAR in the version 3.7

There has been a small script "phpunit" installed to /usr/bin and the Sources were at /usr/share/php in a folder named "PHPUnit".

Zend Framework 1 requires to include "PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php" and therefor I need to make shure the sources of PHPUnit are available through the include path (including /usr/share/php worked).

With PHPUnit 4.0 there are no sources seperated anymore. There is just 1 really big script "phpunit" installed to /usr/bin which seems to include all phpunit sources.

So there is my Question:
How to make shure Zend Framework 1 works with PHPUnit as it worked before?
Is there a way to install PHPUnit 3.7 through PEAR for the meantime this problem gets resolved either by PHPUnit, PEAR or Zend Framework?
Can I extract the files from /usr/bin/phpunit?
Can I use a secret/hidden/unknown/silly option for PEAR to forbid those kind of install? Or is there any other possibility I cannot think of how to solve this?

For my builds it is important to have a script named "phpunit" in the PATH od the OS.

Comment: This really big file of PHPUnit is a PHAR [1] file. PHPUnit is only shipped as PHAR file via PEAR since a while. But I don't know how to make it work with ZF1. Maybe you can make it working via Composer.

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I will answer this question my own, since I now know my mistake in the try to install the old PHPUnit version by PEAR.

The Command for installing the old version 3.7.37, which I have at the old virtual machine, is

```
sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit-3.7.27
```

Since this is the worst possible solution I have it would be nice to receive additional answers. By the end of this day I gonna accept the best.